# Count the number of consecutive identical objects with Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I want to count the number of identical objects one after another with the Java 8 stream. How do I do that? If I have a list of

```
3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3
```

I want the result to be

```
[3-2] [5-3] [6-1] [3-2]
```

My naive try without Java 8 streams:

```
private static List<ValueCount> counteSameValueInRow(List<Integer> Values) {
    List<ValueCount> result = new ArrayList<ValueCount>();
    ValueCount valueCount = null;

    for (int value: Values) {
        if (valueCount == null) {
            valueCount = new ValueCount(value);
        } else if (valueCount.value == value){
            valueCount.numberof++;
        } else {
            result.add(valueCount);
            valueCount = new ValueCount(value);
        }
    }
    result.add(valueCount);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Streams are not suited for this at all. I recommend you stick with the solution you already have.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is comparable to a `collect` on a stream. You are taking each number and summarize it into a list of "groups". `Collectors.groupingBy()` comes to mind, but that would group the numbers accross the whole list, i.e. just count the occurrences of each number. Using the `Stream.collect(Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer)` method to implement a custom collect, you can do something like this:

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3);

values.stream().collect(LinkedList<List<Integer>>::new, (list, value) -> {
    if (list.isEmpty() || !list.getLast().get(0).equals(value))
    {
        list.add(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    list.getLast().add(value);
}, (list1, list2) -> {
    if (list1.getLast().get(0).equals(list2.getFirst().get(0)))
    {
        list1.getLast().addAll(list2.getFirst());
        list2.removeFirst();
    }
    list1.addAll(list2);
}).forEach(group -> System.out.println("[" + group.get(0) + "-" + group.size() + "]"));
```

Note that I used `ArrayList`s to collect duplicates. You can use your `ValueCount` class for this purpose which might make it more readable.

The stream in this example does not improve your code in terms of readability, but enables the use of parallel processing. Look at the third parameter of the collect method. That one combines two intermediate results in case the stream was processed in parallel.

To try it in parallel, replace `stream()` with `parallelStream()` and put a `sysout` in the third parameter's lambda to see when two intermediate results are merged. Note that parallel processing will only benefit you if your list is very large.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a refactoring to get better readability after Malte Hartwig's proposal. Here is the result

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3);

    BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> predicate = (value1, value2) -> value1.equals(value2);

    Supplier<BiConsumer<LinkedList<ValueCount>, Integer>> accumulator = 
        () -> (list, value) -> {
        if (list.isEmpty() || !predicate.test(list.getLast().getFirstValue(), value)) {
            list.add(new ValueCount());
        }
        list.getLast().add(value);
    };

    Supplier<BiConsumer<LinkedList<ValueCount>, LinkedList<ValueCount>>> combiner = () -> (list1, list2) -> {
        if (list1.getLast().getFirstValue().equals(list2.getFirst().getFirstValue())) {
            list1.getLast().addAll(list2.getFirst());
            list2.removeFirst();
        }
        list1.addAll(list2);
    };

    values.stream().collect(LinkedList::new, accumulator.get(), combiner.get())
            .forEach(group -> System.out.println(group));
}

private static class ValueCount {
    private List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    public String toString() { return "[" + lista.get(0) + "-" + lista.size() + "]";}
    public void add(Integer value) { lista.add(value);}
    public Integer getFirstValue() { return lista.get(0);}
    public void addAll(ValueCount first) { lista.addAll(first.getAll());}
    private Collection<? extends Integer> getAll() { return lista;}
}
```